# mobx react for deleting row should trigger twice to update view

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mobx

I have a problem with `mobx` in `react`.
I made a table with `antd` component. I want to when clicked on row delete that row 
so when I click I trigger an @action that use delete method and then triggers the @action for the get request . when I click on delete icon it deletes in my server that I made with nodeJs but it won't re render the table and when I click on delete again it will re-render. but in network tab both of the request are the same.
appreciate any help.
my nodeJs delete method:

```
app.delete("/api/accommodation/delete/:id", function(req, res) {
fs.readFile("./data/accommodation.json", function(err, data) {
  var deleteId = req.params.id;
  console.log("deleted", deleteId);
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
  parsedData.map((item, index) => {
    if (item.id == deleteId) {
      parsedData.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });
  fs.writeFile(
    "./data/accommodation.json",
    JSON.stringify(parsedData),
    function(error, writeData) {}
  );
});

res.end();
```

});

my table:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
const ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
import { Layout, Table, Row, Col, Button, Input, Pagination } from "antd";
import { inject, observer } from "mobx-react";
import { observable } from "mobx";
import { MdSearch } from "react-icons/md";

const { Header, Content } = Layout;
const Search = Input.Search;

@inject("stores")
@observer
export default class Services extends Component {
  @observable
  store = this.props.stores.services;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.store.getAccommodationData(this.store.tableQuery);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout>
          <Header>
            <h3>خدمات</h3>
          </Header>

          <Content style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}>
            <Row>
              <Col span={20} offset={2}>
                <Row>
                  <Col span={2}>
                    <Button type="primary">new +</Button>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <br />

                <Row>
                  <Col span={5}>
                    <Input
                      placeholder="Enter your username"
                      prefix={<MdSearch />}
                      value={this.store.searchField}
                      onChange={e => this.store.onSearch(e)}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </Row>

                <br />
                <Row>
                  <Col span={24}>
                    <Table
                      dataSource={this.store.dataSource}
                      columns={this.store.columns}
                      pagination={false}
                      rowKey={record => record.id}
                      onChange={this.store.changeTable}
                    />
                    <Row>
                      <br />
                      <Col span={24}>
                        <Pagination
                          style={{ direction: "ltr" }}
                          defaultCurrent={1}
                          total={this.store.totalPage}
                          pageSize={1}
                          onChange={e => this.store.pageChange(e)}
                        />
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Content>
        </Layout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

my store:

```js
import { observable, action } from "mobx";
import React from "react";
import { MdEdit } from "react-icons/md";

export default class Services {
  @observable
  dataSource = [];

  @observable
  columns = [
    {
      title: "Id",
      dataIndex: "id",
      key: "id"
    },
    {
      sorter: true,
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      key: "name"
    },
    {
      sorter: true,
      title: "Provider",
      dataIndex: "provider",
      key: "provider"
    },
    {
      sorter: true,
      title: "Location",
      dataIndex: "location",
      key: "location"
    },
    {
      title: "Type",
      dataIndex: "type",
      key: "type"
    },
    {
      title: "Action",
      key: "action",
      render: (text, record) => (
        <span>
          <MdEdit
            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            onClick={() => this.deleteRow(record)}
          />
        </span>
      )
    }
  ];

  @observable
  totalPage = 0;

  @observable
  currentPage = 1;

  @observable
  tableQuery = {
    c: 5,
    p: this.currentPage,
    s: "",
    sk: "",
    d: "",
    q: ""
  };

  @observable
  sortKey = "";

  @observable
  sortOrder = "";

  @observable
  searchField = "";

  @action
  deleteRow(record) {
    console.log("deleted");
    this.deleteData(record.id);
  }

  @action
  async deleteData(id) {
    fetch("http://localhost:1234/api/accommodation/delete/" + id, {
      method: "DELETE"
    })
      .then(this.getAccommodationData(this.tableQuery))
      .then(console.log(this.dataSource));
  }

  @action
  changeTable = (pagination, filters, sorter) => {
    this.sortKey = sorter.field;
    this.sortOrder = sorter.order;
    this.tableQuery.sk = this.sortKey;
    if (this.sortOrder == "ascend") {
      this.tableQuery.s = "asc";
    } else if (this.sortOrder == "descend") {
      this.tableQuery.s = "dec";
    }
    this.getAccommodationData(this.tableQuery);
  };

  @action
  pageChange(pageNumber) {
    this.currentPage = pageNumber;
    this.tableQuery.p = this.currentPage;
    this.getAccommodationData(this.tableQuery);
  }

  @action
  onSearch(e) {
    this.searchField = e.target.value;
    if (this.searchField != "") {
      this.tableQuery.d = 1;
    }
    this.tableQuery.q = this.searchField;
    this.getAccommodationData(this.tableQuery);
  }

  @action
  async getAccommodationData(query = this.tableQuery) {
    fetch(
      "http://localhost:1234/api/accommodation?" +
        "c=" +
        query.c +
        "&p=" +
        query.p +
        "&s=" +
        query.s +
        "&sk=" +
        query.sk +
        "&d=" +
        query.d +
        "&q=" +
        query.q,
      {
        method: "GET",
        cors: "no-cors"
      }
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.dataSource = data.requestedData;
        this.totalPage = data.total;
      });
  }
}
```

[image: my network tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem myself.
when I called the get function in my delete function promise I didn't return it
I should did this :

```
.then(() => this.getAccommodationData(this.tableQuery))
```

instead of this:

```
.then(this.getAccommodationData(this.tableQuery))
```